# Default kotlin IDE but I want it in Java so that I can follow along

Tags: android, kotlin

I am taking a course in android development, the tutorial are all set up in Java but my android studio is 3.0.1 with a default kotlin set up and constraints layout.

I have managed to override the constraint layout to linearlayout and sometimes RelativeLayout.

However, I need the Java script page to be java not kotlin. Often when I copy java code into the environment, the IDE detects it and convert it for me into kotlin equivalent.

Now I am getting mature in the learning process, I want to start writing these code myself but the Java writing styles are constituting nuisance on the IDE  with many errors.

How do I just make it accept java as against the default kotlin ?

Comment: AFAIK, Android Studio will only convert Java code into Kotlin when it is told to do so (e.g., by copying into a Kotlin file). If you want Java code, create a Java class file (e.g., File > New > Java Class).

Comment: Ok, then. What about the MainActivity class that contains the appCompatActivity? Is there no way to make it java?

Comment: Create a new project, and do not choose "Add Kotlin support" in the initial page of the new-project wizard. Or, delete your existing `MainActivity.kt` file and create a new activity, choosing Java as the language.

Comment: Ok, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Two things to fix this:

1. When making new files, be sure that you're always creating a Java class, not a a Kotlin
2. When creating a project where you don't want Kotlin at all, be sure that you disable the options that says "Add Kotlin Support"

Basically, don't give the IDE a reason to think you'd want Kotlin at all

Comment: Spot on, I think I grab that tight!